# How to use range() for decimals

Tags: python

I have defined a function to loop over the range of 10^-9 to 10^3 for every 10^3 steps.

```
 import math

   a = 2 
   b = 2 
   def f(L): 
      f = ab/L 

  for i in range(10**-9, 10**3, 10**3): 
       print (f(i))
```

I get following error with this code:

```
TypeError: range() integer step argument expected, got float.
```

Comment: And what don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't think he's confused by the error message. His topic line contains the question: what is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: You should look into the numpy module

Comment: I want to know a way to obtain this range without  typing it out [10**-9, 10**-8, 10**-7, 10**-6, 10**-5, 10**-4, 10**-3, 10**-2, 10**-1,1, 10**1, 10**2, 10**3]. I tried np.arange() still not luck.

Comment: np.logspace(-9, 3, 11) woks.

Comment: `np.logspace(-9, 3, 11)` is neither equivalent to your original code (which will only give [1e-9] using `np.arange`), nor [10**-9, 10**-8, 10**-7, 10**-6, 10**-5, 10**-4, 10**-3, 10**-2, 10**-1,1, 101[sic], 102[sic], 10**3]. For the latter, you'd want `np.logspace(9,3,13)`. Also, use `1e-9` instead of `10**-9`.